# Excel Save As PDF And Overwrite Existing

Tags: excel, vba

Here is the Problem I have encountered.

I have created a Excel Project. At a point in my project I save the current workbook as a PDF and update a existing workbook with log information and hyperlink to the PDF (**Step1**).

At another point in the project I re-save the project as the same PDF (to Overwrite Existing PDF). At the point I try to re-save the PDF I receive:

> run-time error-1004

Document is not saved, may be opened or error may have been encountered. Here is the 2 scripts I use.

I think maybe it might have something to do with the second part of **step1** script (when opening a workbook and updating log info, that it may not be closing properly)

Please any help would be greatly appreciated, as I will continue to trouble shoot.

**Step1:**

```
Sub Step1()
Dim rng As Range
Dim nwb As Workbook
Dim FileName As String
Dim var
Dim var1
Dim var2
Dim var3
Dim var4
Dim var5
Dim var6
var1 = frmsetup.cmbauditor.Text
var2 = frmsetup.lblsequence.Caption
var3 = frmsetup.cmbtrimstyle.Text
var = "SEQ-" & frmsetup.lblsequence.Caption & " "
var4 = frmsetup.lbldate.Caption
FileName = var & var4

With Sheets(Array("END RESULTS", "DRIVER SEAT", "PASSENGER SEAT", "40% SEAT", "60% SEAT", "RSC SEAT")).Select
ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, FileName:= _
    "H:\APPLICATIONS\SEAT AUDIT\QUERY RESULTS\SEAT AUDIT - PDF\" & FileName & ".pdf", Quality:=xlQualityStandard, _
    IncludeDocProperties:=True, IgnorePrintAreas:=False, OpenAfterPublish:= _
    False
End With
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.WindowState = xlMaximized
```

This is the next part of the **step1**, it opens a existing workbook and adds log information including hyperlink to pdf:

```
Set nwb = Workbooks.Open("H:\APPLICATIONS\SEAT AUDIT\LOG FILES\Seat Audit Log.xlsm")
With Sheets("Seat Audit Log")
nextrow = Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1
Cells(nextrow, 1).Value = var1
Cells(nextrow, 2).Value = var2
Cells(nextrow, 3).Value = var3
Cells(nextrow, 4).Value = var4
Set rng = .Range("E" & nextrow)
rng.Parent.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=rng, Address:="H:\APPLICATIONS\SEAT AUDIT\QUERY RESULTS\SEAT AUDIT - PDF\" & FileName & ".pdf", TextToDisplay:="CLICK HERE!"
End With
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
ActiveWorkbook.Save
ActiveWindow.Close
End Sub
```

This is the **Step2** re-save as PDF to overwrite existing PDF from Step1:

```
Sub Step2()
Dim FileName As String
Dim var
Dim var4
var = "SEQ-" & frmsetup.lblsequence.Caption & " "
var4 = frmsetup.lbldate.Caption
FileName = var & var4

With Sheets(Array("END RESULTS", "DRIVER SEAT", "PASSENGER SEAT", "40% SEAT", "60% SEAT", "RSC SEAT", "ACTIONS")).Select
ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, FileName:= _
    "H:\APPLICATIONS\SEAT AUDIT\QUERY RESULTS\SEAT AUDIT - PDF\" & FileName & ".pdf", Quality:=xlQualityStandard, _
    IncludeDocProperties:=True, IgnorePrintAreas:=False, OpenAfterPublish:= _
    False
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Is the PDF open when you are trying to saveas PDF again?

Comment: Davexcel, You are right didnot see that pdf was open in form, i needed to unload form, slipped my mind

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most of your `With` blocks appear to be poorly constructed and may be contributing to some errors (or, maybe not, it's hard to say for certain). Generally, you'll qualify objects to the `With` object. In your case, you don't seem to be doing that except for one or two lines of code.

You don't need variables to represent form controls, and doing so the way you have done is making your code more complicated to read. I've revised Step1 accordingly.

However, to the main problem: generally when you are trying to `Save` a file, you first need to check if the same file already exists, and if so, delete it.

```
Sub Step1()
Dim rng As Range
Dim nwb As Workbook
Dim FileName As String


FileName = "SEQ-" & frmsetup.lblsequence.Caption & " " & frmsetup.lbldate.Caption
'## Add the PATH and EXTENSION to the filename
FileName = "H:\APPLICATIONS\SEAT AUDIT\QUERY RESULTS\SEAT AUDIT - PDF\" & FileName & ".pdf"

With Sheets(Array("END RESULTS", "DRIVER SEAT", "PASSENGER SEAT", "40% SEAT", "60% SEAT", "RSC SEAT")).Select
ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, FileName:= _
    FileName, Quality:=xlQualityStandard, _
    IncludeDocProperties:=True, IgnorePrintAreas:=False, OpenAfterPublish:= _
    False
End With
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.WindowState = xlMaximized

**'This is the next part of the step1, it opens a existing workbook and adds log information including hyperlink to pdf'**

Set nwb = Workbooks.Open("H:\APPLICATIONS\SEAT AUDIT\LOG FILES\Seat Audit Log.xlsm")
With Sheets("Seat Audit Log")
    nextrow = Range("B" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1
    .Cells(nextrow, 1).Value = frmsetup.cmbauditor.Text
    .Cells(nextrow, 2).Value = frmsetup.lblsequence.Caption
    .Cells(nextrow, 3).Value = frmsetup.cmbtrimstyle.Text
    .Cells(nextrow, 4).Value = frmsetup.lbldate.Caption
    .Set rng = .Range("E" & nextrow)
    rng.Parent.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=rng, Address:=FileName, TextToDisplay:="CLICK HERE!"
End With
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
ActiveWorkbook.Save
ActiveWindow.Close
End Sub

Sub Step2()
Dim FileName As String

FileName = "SEQ-" & frmsetup.lblsequence.Caption & " " & frmsetup.lbldate.Caption
'## Add the PATH and EXTENSION to the filename
FileName = "H:\APPLICATIONS\SEAT AUDIT\QUERY RESULTS\SEAT AUDIT - PDF\" & FileName & ".pdf"

'## Check to see if this file exists, and delete it if it does
If Dir(FileName) <> vbNullString Then
    Kill FileName
End If

With Sheets(Array("END RESULTS", "DRIVER SEAT", "PASSENGER SEAT", "40% SEAT", "60% SEAT", "RSC SEAT", "ACTIONS")).Select
ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, FileName:= _
    FileName, Quality:=xlQualityStandard, _
    IncludeDocProperties:=True, IgnorePrintAreas:=False, OpenAfterPublish:= _
    False
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, I have run into a error step2 kill FileName (wrong number of arguments or invalid property assignments

Comment: Kill FileName  is highlighted

Comment: Try Kill (Filename). Of that doesn't work, then  can you tell me what value of `FileName` and whether such file exists?

Comment: David, thanks for fixing my code, it makes more sense now without clutter, for the Issue that I had started and asked for help has been resolved, it took a while to understand, that it was me the whole time, the form that i did not unload, was still carry the existance of the pdf file, and that was why it would not save.  Sorry for the nusence, i am just learning as i go.  Thanks